# How to draw curves in Flex Viewer?

Tags: arcgis-flex-api, arcgis-flex-viewer

I want to draw curves from a given point to another in Sample Flex Viewer like shown below.

Any help?

[image: Routes]

[image]

Comment: Search for a Geodesic curve widget.

Comment: Cant't find one. :(